# Animatin constantly runs

Tags: android, animation

I want run one animation and then animation one finished, second animation is started. I write this code but when i run this program, animation constantly runs! and  not finished. Why? What is the problem??

```
public class Splash extends Activity{

Animation animation1;
Animation animation2;
Animation animation3;
ImageView image;
ImageButton circleProduct; 
ImageButton circleIntroduce;
ImageButton circleMore;
ImageButton circleContact;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    animation1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.bounce);

    circleProduct=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCircleProduct);
    circleIntroduce=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCircleIntroduce);
    circleMore=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCircleMore);
    circleContact=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.btnCircleContact);

    image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
    image.startAnimation(animation1);

    animation1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            circleProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            circleProduct.startAnimation(animation1);
            circleContact.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            circleContact.startAnimation(animation1);
            circleIntroduce.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            circleIntroduce.startAnimation(animation1);
            circleMore.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            circleMore.startAnimation(animation1);
        }
    });
 }
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running the same animation again on `onAnimationEnd` method.-

```
circleMore.startAnimation(animation1);
```

Therefore, every time `animation1` finished, it will start again, unless you start a different animation with a different `animationListener`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are starting the same animation, `animation1`, in your listener, so you have created a loop.

Create another animation instance for the animations you have to launch in the `onAnimationEnd` method.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that when a1 ends you start a1 again and not a2.

I would suggest you that you form an `AnimationSet` out of your thee animations, where you set the start offset of a2 to the duration of a1 and the start offset of a3 to the duration of a1 + the duration of a2.
Then you apply the whole animation set to the view and it will play one animation after another and end after the third.